# RadTreeView all nodes have same aligment

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, telerik

How I can have the same alignment for all nodes(Parent && Children)

Could you please see the following images (I am trying to do the same on pik1).
"Bedding Features" is root and other nodes are leafs (Children).

[image]

[image]

I am using Telerik RadTreeView

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="TreeView1" ItemsIndent="0"  ShowLineImages="false" RegisterWithScriptManager ="true" ForeColor="Black" CheckBoxes="true" runat="server"  OnNodeCheck="TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged" >
   </telerik:RadTreeView>



 private void FillTree()
    {
        //get all tree 

        DataTable TreeDataTable = new DataTable();
        TreeDataTable = DSCAttribute.GetAttributeFullTree();
        TreeView1.DataTextField = "Name";
        TreeView1.DataValueField = "Name";
        TreeView1.DataFieldID = "Id";
        TreeView1.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";
        TreeView1.DataSource = TreeDataTable;
        TreeView1.DataBind();
}
```

I Need away to eliminate the space before children nodes ..thanks ?!

Comment: Show how you bind it.

Comment: Also add you data model and tell whats wrong with your code. How it look.

Comment: @mwisnicki ... i just want to remove space before children node so children nodes and parent nodes will be have same left alignment  ..the bind and data model is correct ..

Comment: @mwisnicki question updated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The treeveiw is supposed to have this padding to show hierarchy. Thus, you should consider flattening the data source and just show everything in one level.

Or, you can try hacking it by overriding its CSS rules. Here is a basic example to get you started:

```
        /*remove padding*/
        div.RadTreeView .rtLI
        {
            padding-left: 0; 
        }

        /*remove dotted lines*/
        div.RadTreeView .rtLines .rtLI::before,
        div.RadTreeView .rtLines .rtOut::before
        {
            display: none;
        }

        /*hide expand/collapse icons*/
        span.rtMinus,
        span.rtPlus
        {
            display: none;
        }
```

and some sample markup

```
        <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" CheckBoxes="true">
            <Nodes>
                <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="root" Expanded="true">
                    <Nodes>
                        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="leaf 1" Expanded="true">
                            <Nodes>
                                <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="subleaf 1"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="subleaf 2"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="subleaf 3"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                            </Nodes>
                        </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="leaf 2"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="leaf 3"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    </Nodes>
                </telerik:RadTreeNode>
            </Nodes>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Comment: padding on children nodes doesn't removing by using attached css ?!

Comment: Note the Lightweight RenderMode from my example. This helps the CSS I showed you equalize all nodes. Also, note the very first sentence of my answer. You are using the wrong control, consider a grid, listview, repeater or something else that is not hierarchical by design to avoid having to hack it.